# Using jquery from angular directive does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to implement jquery-ui's sortable on the elements inside the ng-repeat.

Problem : i cannot actually do the sortable action on the elements inside the ng-repeat.

I've checked for answers. My code seems similar to most answers which apparently work, but my code doesn't work

Below is the html snippet:

```
<div class="container-fluid rt-widget-list-dim-adj">
    <div my-dir>
        <div ng-repeat="widget in model.widgets" ng-switch="widget.widgetType">
            <div ng-switch-when="HEADER">
                <ng-include src="'views/widget/widget-header.view.client.html'">
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="IMAGE">
                <ng-include src="'views/widget/widget-image.view.client.html'">
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="YOUTUBE">
                <ng-include src="'views/widget/widget-youtube.view.client.html'">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my app.js:

```
(function(){
    angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute', 'myDir']);
})();
```

below is my custom directive:

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module("myApp", [])
        .directive("myDir", makeSortable);

    function makeSortable() {
        var directive = {
            restrict : 'ACE',
            link : linker
        };
        function linker(scope, element, attrb) {
            element.sortable();
        }
        return directive;
    }
})();
```

Comment: your "element" on element.sortable() is probably not a jquery element

Comment: what do you mean by not a jquery element? I assume that since the my-dir is the parent, all its children can be sorted.

Comment: It doesn't work for obvious reason. ng-include templates are loaded asynchronously. Child elements don't exist yet when link function runs. There's no good way to handle it in its current state. Consider creating directives for each ng-switch-when case and using them instead of ng-include.

Answer (score 0):

element in linker function args is not jQuery, it is a jqLite wrapper.
If you want to apply jQuery, try this:

```
$j(element[0]).sortable();
```

Comment: This doesn't work too. But `$(element).sortable();` does work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Depend on what is used for jQuery reference: $, $j, jQuery. But $ is not a good practice.

Comment: `element` is jQuery element. `angular.element === $` when jQuery is loaded.